# Can I access the current component in the HTML template in Ionic/Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

If for example I have a simple component, can I access the reference to it right in the HTML code instead of using `@ViewChild` in the `typescript` or `javascript` file?

```
<ion-col></ion-col>
```

Something like the following where `this` is an actual reference to the current `ion-col`:

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let col of row.cols; col.viewChild = this"></ion-col>
```

The goal of this is to have the component reference in a class that is not a component and to add children to it from there. I want to add components programmatically to the `ion-row` where the rows are not static, but generated.

The alternative I can think about is extending `ion-col` but that doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Can you share a bit more context about your use case? what is your data model that should "feed" the template?

Comment: I'm trying to generate a sort of dashboard based on the grid, where users can only define the name and type of a cell (first phase). This means I don't know beforehand what each cell holds or how many there are, I'll get that information from an API.